# jquery event.target attribute not working in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, attributes

i have a datalist in my page. it has Hyperlink

```
<a href='#' class="lnkviewcontentclick" id="contentlink" runat="server" recid='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"link")%>' >Click</a>
```

and my script is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".lnkviewcontentclick").click(
        function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if (confirm("Are you sure you wish to delete this user?")) {
                var lnk = $(event.target).attr('recid');
                alert(lnk);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

but the it return **undefined**

**the above code got worked in php**

pls help

Comment: where is your runat="server" dont use html controls inside asp data presentation controls without runat attribute

Comment: @naveen even if i add runat="server" it returns same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a click callback, you can use `this` instead of event.target to get the element.  Event.target is used when events bubble up.